# Is there a way to get the label attached to an element to javascript?

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to delete a label attached to a check box, as well as the checkbox itself. I can easily delete the checkbox using

```
<script>
    var Check = document.createElement("input")
                Check.setAttribute("name", Name);
                Check.setAttribute("id", Name)
                

                var Label = document.createElement("label")
                var labelText = document.createTextNode(Name);

                Label.setAttribute("for", Name)

                Label.appendChild(labelText);

                var LineBreak = document.createElement("br");

                Check.setAttribute("type", "checkbox")



                document.getElementById("MyList").appendChild(Check);
                document.getElementById("MyList").appendChild(Label);
                    document.getElementById("MyList").appendChild(LineBreak);

                    Check.addEventListener('change', event =>{
                        
                        document.getElementById("MyList").removeChild(event.target)
                        
            }
        </script>
```

but I can't get the label. Any ideas?

Comment: Please update your question with HTML using the snippet tool `[<>]` in the edit toolbar.

Comment: We have no idea where in your structure the label is located. Please always present a _proper_ [mre], when asking a question like this.

Answer (score 1):

You already have the handle to the label in a variable `Label`. The variable is visible in the closure. Therefore you can simply delete it via `Label.remove()` inside event listener function.

```
Check.addEventListener('change', event =>{
  document.getElementById("MyList").removeChild(event.target)
  Label.remove();                      
}
```

See how to [remove element from the DOM](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Element/remove)

Comment: You could also do `Check.remove()` instead of having to get the list and removing the target

Comment: Of course! That would be further improvement.

Comment: The problem with that is I'm creating this as part of a list, so just using label would delete the last used label

Comment: OK, if this does not work for you, you can try using attribute selector. Label has "for" attribute, which refers to the ID of the checkbox, which is also `event.target.id` inside the listener function. For example: `document.querySelector(\`[for="${event.target.id}"]\`).remove();`

Answer (score 0):

You need to select the DOM element correctly. The `Event.target` is referencing your `input`. You can [traverse the DOM with an existing element](https://zellwk.com/blog/dom-traversals/) or select it globally as such.

```
document.querySelector('label').remove()
```

Edit: after you added more code and appear to already have the DOM element in a variable, you can simply do `Label.remove()`

Comment: @Pete, thanks updated it. Since he updated the question with more code now, I think ympek's answer is better.

Comment: The issue with that selector is, it will select the first label of the document, not necessarily the correct one.

Comment: @tacoshy that is true, it's always recommended to use data-attributes to select DOM elements. But I wanted to point out the root of the issue without extra overhead.

Answer (score 0):

Your attempt is way to difficult!
Simply use the `remove()` function:

```js
// id for element to remove
let id = 'MyList';

// removed the input with that id
document.querySelector(`#${id}`).remove();

// removes the label connected to an input with the id
document.querySelector(`[for="${id}"]`).remove();
```

```html
<label for="MyList">Test</label><input type="checkbox" id="MyList">
```

Comment: Out of curiosity, why do you create a variable out of the ID and interpolate it? Seems redundant to me.

Comment: Because I use the variable at 2 points. Makes it easier and makes it logically easier to understand and replicate. Half of the programming is to actually make a program work, the other half is to make it readable and understandable for others (maintenance and project transfer).